# Cannot republish a InfoPath form after a migration

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I'm working on a migration project from SP 2007 to SP2010. I use a standard `Mount-SPContentDatabase` approach to perform the upgrade.

I have an issue with a form library. After the upgrade, I want to republish the form library template. Some of the datasources has to be changed.

However, when I try to publish, even I can fill all the publish wizard steps, an error occurs at the very end of the process :

> Infopath cannot save the following form: http://servername/sitecoll/subweb/formlib  This document library was either renamed or deleted, or network problem are preventing the file from being saved. If this problem persists, contact your administrator.

If I try to create a new form library (in the same subweb) instead of upgrading the existing one, everything goes fine. However, as soon as I try to republish it, the error appears.

What can goes wrong ? Uls logs does not help me much... I have entries like this, but I don't know how to understand it :

```
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfc    High    The ListFormBody attribute in the forms schema was found but no child elements exist. Failed with 0x80004005, web web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}    966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfz    High    CITPProj::AppendFormSchema failed with 0x80004005.  Type is DisplayForm, FormID is 0, web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}.  Ignoring failure and will continue.  966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfc    High    The ListFormBody attribute in the forms schema was found but no child elements exist. Failed with 0x80004005, web web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}    966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfz    High    CITPProj::AppendFormSchema failed with 0x80004005.  Type is EditForm, FormID is 0, web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}.  Ignoring failure and will continue. 966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfc    High    The ListFormBody attribute in the forms schema was found but no child elements exist. Failed with 0x80004005, web web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}    966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
w3wp.exe (0x1D2C)   0x1D94  SharePoint Foundation   General tkfz    High    CITPProj::AppendFormSchema failed with 0x80004005.  Type is NewForm, FormID is 0, web http://server/sitecoll/subweb, list {2483AE56-E08B-408D-8CAE-761B6482CD3E}.  Ignoring failure and will continue.  966ef935-3567-4171-b41c-eea22ea64eb2
```

<s>**[Edit]**</s>

Don't know if it can help, but with Powershell, I can get the form template file :

```
$list = .... # get the list 
$file = $list.Rootfolder.Subfolders["Forms"].Files | ? { $_.Url -Match ".xsn" }
```

And, I don't know the purpose of this property, `ServerRedirected` property is `true` :

```
> $file.ServerRedirected
$true
```

A newly created form, with working republishing has also this parameter set to true...

**[Edit2]**

Using Fiddler, I compared the http message between the migrated form a new form. I discover that the upgrade form throw an Http 302 response (redirection) between the path to my xsn and the form services url :

- Source Url : http://server/sitecoll/subweb/formlib/forms/template.xsn
- Redirected url : http://server/sitecoll/subweb/_layouts/form.aspx?form= formlib/forms/template.xsn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems occurred only on the development environment. Everything is going fine on the production plaforms, so I put this issue is the mystical things drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue when you try to open your original form that you published to the library from somewhere other than the library itself (meaning you created the form, saved it somewhere, published it, and then reopened it from wherever you saved it).

You might try opening the template right from the library template.xsn.  Once you open it from there, simply republish it back to the library without making any changes.  Then make your changes and publish.

Comment: it's not as easy. AS the form has been migrated from server A (SP2007) to server B (SP2010), there are data connections that are wrong. I cannot republish the form without fixing the data connections.

Comment: FYI, I've also try to open directly the xsn form from the explorer view. Then, with no modification, I tried to republish it. No success. I've also tested using the [script from Brian Cartmel](http://sharepintblog.com/2011/06/07/updating-infopath-form-templates-and-data-connections-with-powershell/), still with no success.